# Функция принимает положительное число и возвращает true, если оно чисто, иначе false

Tags: javascript

Нужно сделать проверку что «isTidy» должна возвращать «false»
для убывания упорядоченных цифр.
И isTidy должна возвращать false,
если первая цифра не в порядке.

```
    function isTidy(number) {

    let numToStr = String(number);
    let prevNum = [0]
    for (let i = 1; i < numToStr.length; i++) {

        let current = numToStr[i];
        current = Number(current)

        if (current <= prevNum) {
            prevNum = current
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
return true
}

let resulIsTidy = isTidy(1234)
console.log(resulIsTidy)
```

Comment: А теперь, внимание, вопрос...

Comment: Какой вопрос. что не так?

Comment: Зачем ты написал этот вопрос? Просто рассказать? Если нет, то опиши свою проблему.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Все довольно просто, у вас была ошибка в этом условии: if (current <= prevNum), их просто нужно поменять местами. Вот рабочий пример:

```
function isTidy(number) {
      let inputNumber = String(number);
      let prevNum = inputNumber[0];
      let current;
      for (let i = 1; i < inputNumber.length; i++) {
          current = Number(inputNumber[i]);

          if (prevNum <= current) {
              prevNum = current;
          } else return false
      }
      return true
  }

  console.log( isTidy(1234) ); // return True
  console.log( isTidy(2182) ); // return False
```